# How to sign out from google without opening browser?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-drive-api, disconnect

In a windows form application in c# that use google Drive API, I'm trying to sign out the user currently connected. I tried some solutions but no one is working. The code is executed but the user still connected when I'm looking in my browser.

Solution 1 (WebClient):

```
WebClient g = new WebClient();
g.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout");
```

Solution 2:

```
Process.Start("https://accounts.google.com/Logout") //Working but open a browser
```

Solution 3 (WebRequest):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/Logout");
request.Method = "GET";
request.GetResponse();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 seems to work. Google Sign-in authorized you with an access token that is gathered by your auth flow that needs a signed-in Google account. If you want to log the user out of Google network, you should redirect him/her to `https://accounts.google.com/Logout?&continue=[nextUrl]`.

You can also revoke the users Token by calling `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}`.

Check this [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664272/google-api-oauth-nativeapplicationclient-oauth2authenticator-logout) which might help.

Comment: I'm in a windows form application so I asked me if it's possible to sign out of google without open a browser. Several people will connect their google account on my application so to avoid wrong access to another account, I need to disconnect the current google user.